# a dictionary string causes sys.argv to split a single string argument into multiple parts (vscode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, argv

I have a program I'm running similar to:

```
some_script.py --arg1="{'a':'1','b':'2'}"
```

in vscode I'm trying to run this by adding to my launch.json

```
args:[
"arg1=/"{'a':'1','b':'2'}/" "
]
```

and if I break point inside of some_script.py and run:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

I get:

```
['<cwd>/some_script.py', "--arg1='a':'1'", "--arg1='b':'2'"]
```

why is it not:

```
['<cwd>/some_script.py', "--arg1={'a':'1','b':'2'}"]
```

Comment: The *shell* is interpreting the special characters in your arguments. You need to escape the value correctly on the shell, e.g. by surrounding it with quotes.

Comment: i updated my question since it's actually a bit more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple script:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
```

As per docs command line parameters are available in sys.argv[:1], play around see what your script gets. If you need to parse command line parameters check argparse module.

Comment: Thanks but it just doesn't seem right to me that i would need to create my own arg parser. it's arguably the most tested generic component in python. I'd rather find a solution that works with argparser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result below, why not modify "args" in this way:

```
        "args":[
            "--arg1={'a':'1','b':'2'}"
            ],
```

Update:

This works for me.

```
    "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: currentFile",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args":[
                "--arg1={'a':'1','b':'2'}"
                ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. the format you suggest still results with the same problem.